# Passing map location values in modal to parent page which is already opened. using rails, ruby and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, modal-dialog

I've been struggling with this problem for 3 days and hope to find some a nice solution...:

I'm trying to make get Google Maps' current location values(lonlongitude, lat latitude) in inside of a modal, and bring back that those values to the input page's form inputs which are going to be filled out.

Here's my code:

main.html.erb(parent page)

```
<form action="/ask/fine/<%= @chap.id %>" class="col-md-12 clearfix">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading clearfix"> 
        <h1>Current Location</h1>
        <input type="hidden" id="lon" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" id="lat" value="" />       
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_map" value="CURRENT LOCATION CHECK">
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" name="content" placeholder="What's happening?" required></textarea>
    </div>  
  </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block btn-lg" value="Submit">  
</form>
```

_modal_map.html.erb(modal)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Geolocation</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      #map-canvas {
        height: 300px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>

    <script>

var map;

function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 13
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  // Try HTML5 geolocation
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude);

       var lonlon = position.coords.longitude.toString();
       var latlat = position.coords.latitude.toString();

       document.getElementById('lon').innerHTML = lonlon;
       document.getElementById('lat').innerHTML = latlat;

       var lons = position.coords.longitude.toString().substr(0,10);
       var lats = position.coords.latitude.toString().substr(0,10);

       var lonlat = lats + "|" + lons;

       var vReturn = new Object();
        vReturn.lon = lonlon;
        vReturn.lat = latlat;
        window.returnValue = vReturn;

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        map: map,
        position: pos,
        content: lonlat
      });

      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
  }
}

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
  if (errorFlag) {
    var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
  } else {
    var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
  }

  var options = {
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
    content: content
  };

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
  map.setCenter(options.position);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);



    </script>
  </head>
<body>
<div id="myModal_map" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="margin-top: 10%;">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">YOUR LOCATION</h4>
                </div>
                    <div class="modal-body" style="height: 350px;">
                    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="hidden" id="lon" value="" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="lat" value="" />
                    <input type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="javascript:return done()" value="SAVE">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script>

function done() {
    var vReturnValue = new Object();
    vReturnValue.lon = document.getElementById('lon').value
    vReturnValue.lat = document.getElementById('lat').value
    window.returnValue = vReturnValue;
});

</script>

</html>
```

I tried using `returnValue` and `sessionStorage` without success. How can I successfully submit those two input values(longitude, latitude) inside the parent page's form?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `window.opener` to reference the parent window from the child window as long as the two pages are served from the same domain.

`window.opener === parentWindow`

If your modal is served from a different domain, you'll need to use `postMessage` hopefully you won't have that issue cause it's pain to set that up.